# JavaScript negative lookahead regular expression producing wrong result

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume the following URL: `http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/ryoyo0/078/Purple100x100/v4/38/e3/b4/38e3b4a2-b422-8d1e-69f2-593fc035c9d4/mzl.vqhwzhhc.100x100-75.jpg`

We want to replace the last occurrence of 100x100 with 256x256. The URL should read:

```
http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/ryoyo0/078/Purple100x100/v4/38/e3/b4/38e3b4a2-b422-8d1e-69f2-593fc035c9d4/mzl.vqhwzhhc.256x256-75.jpg
```

Here's our JavaScript replace method:

```
replace( /100x100(?!100x100)/, '256x256' )
```

Unfortunately, we consistently replace the first, not the last, occurrence.

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Use "I" instead of "we," I am not working on the project with you. (Sure, a very minor thing, but it somewhat annoys me `:P`)

Comment: @Doorknob: perhaps, but s/he *may* be part of a team working on this, for which the 'we' pronoun is specifically correct.

Comment: `100x100(?!100x100)` means "'100x100' not *immediately* followed by '100x100'".

Comment: `/100x100\-(\d+)/, '256x256-\1'` should also work, (if the last always have a dash-*int* afterwards.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it...

```
replace( /(.*)100x100/, '$1256x256' )
```

Works by...

1. Capturing everything up to the `100x100` as greedily as possible, with `(.*)`, into group 1
2. Matching the `100x100`
3. Replacing it with the captured group 1, by using `$1` and then adding `256x256` in place of  the non-captured match

*N.B.* This method can only work for the last match (or first if you make the initial capture un-greedy by adding a `?` after the `.*`)

It is usually good to avoid using look-around assertions, for performance reasons, for compatibility with various regex implementations, and I believe also for readability.

### EDIT: Test Script

```
var url = "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/ryoyo0/078/Purple100x100/v4/38/e3/b4/38e3b4a2-b422-8d1e-69f2-593fc035c9d4/mzl.vqhwzhhc.100x100-75.jpg"

console.log(url.replace(/(.*)100x100/, '$1256x256'))

// OUTPUT:
// http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/ryoyo0/078/Purple100x100/v4/38/e3/b4/38e3b4a2-b422-8d1e-69f2-593fc035c9d4/mzl.vqhwzhhc.256x256-75.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry, initially awarded you the answer, but when we tested, this replaces both occurrences of 100x100 instead of only the last one. How to only replace the last occurrence?

Comment: This does only replace the last one (unless you run it twice). I have included a test script, which shows the results I am getting.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Your input already hase `256x256` at the end, and my regex always replaces the last occurrence of `100x100`, so in the case of the input in my answer, and in your question, it replaces the dimensions at the end. In the case of your input you pasted here, it replaces the only one it can find.

Comment: I had taken your question very literally, so `replace the last occurrence` is what my regex does, not replace occurrences that appear near the end, or after a specified character etc...

Comment: yes, sorry. our fault. didn't catch this until just now. actually was coming here to delete our comment, but you spotted the error first. sorry again. this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `replace( /100x100(?!.*100x100)/, '256x256' )`

Adding the `.*` accounts for additional characters between the first occurrence and the last occurrence of `100x100`.

**Note** - While my answer describes what you did wrong in your pattern and how to fix it, the answer provided by Billy Moon is probably a better pattern for what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, based on your suggestion, we awarded the answer to @BillyMoon.

Comment: Hmm, actually both your answer and Billy Moon's replaces both instances of 100x100 (as opposed to only the last one). Are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your negative lookahead to look for the slash also. Since the second occurrence ends with a period, not a slash, that should solve it.

```
/100x100(?!\/)/
```

Comment: Does this not make an assumption about the format of the URL?  Who's to say in some future URL the first occurrence will be followed immediately by a /?

Comment: @Daedalus: you're right, but you have to make *some* kind of assumption about the format.  For example, the first `100x100` is part of a directory name, so it should be safe to assume there will be at least one slash after it *somewhere*.  And the second `100x100` is part of the file name, so we know there *won't* be any more slashes after it.  In other words, change the lookahead to `(?=[^\/]*$)`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, due to possibly misunderstood intentions, which only replaces `100x100`s that appear in the filename part (with no `/` appearing after it in the string) of the url.

```
replace(/100x100([^\/]*)$/, '256x256$1')
```

Works by...

1. matching `100x100`
2. ... followed by capturing into group 1, zero or more, not forward slashes, with `([^\/]*)`
3. ... followed by the end of the string, `$`
4. replacing with `256x256` and the first capture group, `$1`

If there is no match after the last `/` in the string, then no replacements are done.

*N.B.* I checked the speed of this answer, my other answer, and the answer of @Daedalus, and whilst I would normally expect avoiding assertions to speed up the regex, in this case, I have found them to be all identical in speed, and be very fast, running a couple of hundred thousand times a second on my computer.